# Is there an alternative to AWS' lifecycle hooks in Google Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-network-load-balancer

On AWS lifecycle hooks are utilized so the load balancer can query specific details about applications running on instances to, for example, avoid shutting down an instance that has very low CPU but is still running some lightweight service. Is there a similar functionality available in Google Cloud? I haven't located anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually on GCP, there's nothing related with this, just for clarify anything that could monitor directly the application on the VM.

But you can always file a request and vote for new GCP features as following [1](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Where you would need to go to the “Networking” options, then look in the List, if you don't find anything related to your request there, you can "Create a new network issue"[2](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, GCP does not have any feature like lifecycle hook on AWS but we can use the timeouts and mig health-checks to ensure your tasks are completed before putting instance behind lb.